# Want to hide Location Services icon from iPhone status bar

Tags: iphone, core-location

I am running location based program in iPhone. When iPhone receives a location, a small arrow next to battery icon shows. I want this arrow to not show even when location is updating.

Remember, I am working on a jailbreak iPhone.

Any help ???

Comment: Sounds like a shady idea to fool the users of your app.

Comment: Is there any good reason for this desired behavior other then to decept the users of your app?

Comment: In case of theft, this desired behaviour is required

Answer (score 4):

This is impossible.  Your app is using a iOS service that has it built in to display that icon when-ever active.

You could try flicking on location services and once you receive the location, turning it off.
Have this on a timer if you need to update location now and than.  The icon will show when your have it turned on but shouldn't be on for longer than 4-5 seconds.

Comment: There is a free app called CleanStatus on Cydia. This app does the same thing which I want. But I don't want to use it. I want to do it myself. Remember, I am working on a jailbreak iPhone.

Comment: @user1222801 You should mention this on in question that you need to do that in jailbreak as in nonjailbreak phones APPLE won't allow.

Comment: Is there anyone who can help me solve this problem?